# How to Read/Write to an xml file?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an xml file already created that has tags and values for the tags.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Scoreboard>

<Score>
    <username>Ryan</username>
    <points>200</points>
</Score>
```

All I want to be able to do is read the information within the tags as well as write tot he already created xml document with a new tag. If i wanted to add username: Andrew, points: 100, how would i accomplish this? In addition how could i read the xml file so that i could display all the scores and its information?

```
         Read - InputStream is = getAssets().open("highscores2.xml");

                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = 
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);

                Element element = doc.getDocumentElement();
                element.normalize();
         write -   InputStream is = getAssets().open("highscores2.xml");

                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = 
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);

                NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Score");

                Text a = doc.createTextNode("Dylly");
                Element p = doc.createElement("username");
                p.appendChild(a);

                nodes.item(0).getParentNode().insertBefore(p, nodes.item(0));
```

As of right now I have my xml file stored in an asset folder but when i try to write to it I am given an error - saying it is read only. How can I get around this as well?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have spent all afternoon trying to find a solution to this problem and have come up with almost nothing, thanks.

Comment: Assets folder is read only. You need to move the file to the SD Card

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the reply. I will try this and see if it works out!

Comment: @cricket_007 If the user doesn't have an sd card where could I save the file. Is there anyway to save it in the app with it also being readable and writable?

Comment: All devices have SD cards. It doesn't need to be "removable"

Comment: Oh my bad, i took it as an sd card that is physically inserted. Alright, is there somewhere you can recomend for me to learn how to do that? As sad as it might sound i have spent alot of time trying to find an answer.

Comment: Pretty sure it's all covered here. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a class for writing an xml file:

```
serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
writer = new StringWriter(); 
try { 
serializer.setOutput(writer);
serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true); 
serializer.setPrefix(prefix, namespace); 
serializer.startTag(prefix, tagName); 
serializer.attribute(prefix, attrName, value);
serializer.endTag(prefix, tagName); 
serializer.endDocument(); 
return writer.toString();
 } catch (IOException e) {
 throw new RuntimeException(e);
 }
```

And even for reading an xml file:

```
XmlPullParserFactory xmlPullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance(); 
xmlPullParserFactory.setNamespaceAware(true); 
XmlPullParser xmlPullParser = xmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser(); 
xmlPullParser.setInput(new StringReader(xml)); 
return xmlPullParser;
```

Comment: if i didn't want to create a brand new file, how would i write to an already existing file without just creating a new one?I plan on having 5 scores already put in the file when a use downloads the app.

Comment: @RW6 you can use the parser to read the already existing file then create a simple function to load parser content to serializer where you can add what you want and then overwrite the file